# This video can't be read: permissions are given, VideoView and MediaController seem to be correctly defined and used

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, android-video-player

## Aim & Context

I want to display a YouTube video in my fragment, launched when the latter starts.

## The problem

Instead of having the video playing, an error is shown in my app: "This video can't be read". Messages for developers are written in the "Run pannel" of Android Studio. The latter are shown below.

## Implementation

### Explanations

1. I created a `VideoView` in the fragment's layout
2. In the fragment's class, I inflate the `VideoView` and sets the video URI ; I also define the associated `MediaController` ; then I start the `VideoView`.
3. I modified the manifest to set some permissions.

### Sources

#### In fragment's layout

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView3"
    />
```

#### In fragment's class

```
    final VideoView videoView = inflated.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MediaController mc = new MediaController(getContext());
            mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
            mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
            videoView.setMediaController(mc);
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUA_ZvLyVFU"));
            videoView.start();
        }
    });
```

#### In manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xxx.xxx">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

## Reproducing the bug

### Video used to test

The following video won't be used in production. It's just for testing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUA_ZvLyVFU (M. D. GUNDILL is one of the most important theoricians of powerlifting).

### Instructions

Create your fragment's class (activity) and its layout, paste the above code. Don't forget to edit your manifest (paste the above code too). To test, start your fragment.

## Similar questions

1. [How to display Video from URL in my android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691505/how-to-display-video-from-url-in-my-android-app)

I read these post and its answers to implement my video player. Only this answer caught my attention: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24691623/6500085 . However, it doesn't seem to work. I don't want to try another solution, since I think it should normally work.

## Question

How to start the video?

## Errors and Exceptions that are shown

> D/skia: approximate: numPoints=3, lengths[0]=0.000000,
>   totalLength=2.472497, segmentPoints[0]=[0.000000,0.100000]
>       approximate: approximation[0]=0.000000, approximation[1]=0.000000, approximation[2]=0.100000
>       approximate: numPoints=3, lengths[2]=2.472497, totalLength=2.472497, segmentPoints[2]=[2.000000,0.100000]
>       approximate: approximation[6]=1.000000, approximation[7]=2.000000, approximation[8]=0.100000 I/MediaPlayer: Need to enable context aware
>   info V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_setup V/MediaPlayerNative: constructor
>   V/MediaPlayerNative: setListener V/MediaPlayer-JNI: get_session_id()
>   W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUA_ZvLyVFU:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUA_ZvLyVFU D/MediaPlayer:
>   setDataSource IOException | SecurityException happend : 
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUA_ZvLyVFU
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1402)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1253)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1176)
>           at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1163)
>           at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1135)
>           at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1159)
>           at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:399)
>           at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:274)
>           at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:257)
>           at com.example.xxx.xxx.ForewordFragment$1.run(ForewordFragment.java:102)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
>   V/MediaHTTPService:
>   MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@92520d): Cookies: null
>   V/MediaPlayerNative: setVideoSurfaceTexture V/MediaPlayer-JNI:
>   setParameter: key 1400 V/MediaPlayerNative:
>   MediaPlayer::setParameter(1400) V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setAudioStreamType:
>   3 V/MediaPlayerNative: MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
>       setVideoSurfaceTexture V/MediaPlayerNative: prepareAsync V/MediaHTTPService: makeHTTPConnection: CookieManager created:
>   java.net.CookieManager@b758fd3 V/MediaHTTPService:
>   makeHTTPConnection(android.media.MediaHTTPService@92520d):
>   cookieManager: java.net.CookieManager@b758fd3 Cookies: null
>   D/MediaHTTPConnection: setReadTimeOut =  15000ms
>   D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using
>   platform default D/MediaHTTPConnection: setReadTimeout with 15000ms
>   I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false I/zygote64:
>   Do partial code cache collection, code=252KB, data=176KB I/System.out:
>   (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false I/zygote64: After code
>   cache collection, code=252KB, data=176KB
>       Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB D/ViewRootImpl@da487ab[ActivityHandlingFragments]: Relayout returned:
>   old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1
>   surface={valid=true 508417486848} changed=false I/System.out:
>   (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
>       (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false I/MediaHTTPConnection: response code = 200 V/MediaPlayerNative: message received msg=300,
>   ext1=0, ext2=0 V/MediaPlayerNative: Received
>   SEC_MM_PLAYER_CONTEXT_AWARE
>       callback application
>       back from callback
>       message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648 E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648) V/MediaPlayerNative:
>   callback application
>       back from callback E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648) D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648 D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
>   D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
>   D/ViewRootImpl@2ef9a30[ActivityHandlingFragments]: setView =
>   DecorView@21f76a9[] TM=true MM=false
>   D/ViewRootImpl@2ef9a30[ActivityHandlingFragments]:
>   dispatchAttachedToWindow V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game
>   : false, logging : 0
>   D/ViewRootImpl@2ef9a30[ActivityHandlingFragments]: Relayout returned:
>   old=[0,0][0,0] new=[27,792][1053,1200] result=0x7 surface={valid=true
>   508409675776} changed=true D/mali_winsys: EGLint
>   new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface,
>   EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *,
>   EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1218x600]-format:1 D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x7655707d20 D/ScrollView:  onsize change
>   changed  D/ScrollView:  onsize change changed 
>   D/ViewRootImpl@2ef9a30[ActivityHandlingFragments]:
>   MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
>   D/ViewRootImpl@2ef9a30[ActivityHandlingFragments]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT:
>   frame=Rect(27, 792 - 1053, 1200) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 -
>   0, 0) or=1 D/ViewRootImpl@da487ab[ActivityHandlingFragments]:
>   MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
>   D/ViewRootImpl@2ef9a30[ActivityHandlingFragments]: ViewPostIme pointer
>   0 D/ViewRootImpl@2ef9a30[ActivityHandlingFragments]: ViewPostIme
>   pointer 1 D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x7655707d20
>   D/ViewRootImpl@2ef9a30[ActivityHandlingFragments]:
>   dispatchDetachedFromWindow D/InputEventReceiver: channel '108e92
>   com.example.xxx.xxx/com.example.xxx.xxx.ActivityHandlingFragments
>   (client)' ~ Disposing input event receiver.
>       channel '108e92 com.example.xxx.xxx/com.example.xxx.x.ActivityHandlingFragments
>   (client)' ~NativeInputEventReceiver.
>   D/ViewRootImpl@da487ab[ActivityHandlingFragments]:
>   MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent()
>   returned. V/InputMethodManager: Starting input:
>   tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@d9c3763 nm :
>   com.example.x.x ic=null I/InputMethodManager:
>   startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
>   D/SurfaceView: BG show() Surface(name=Background for - SurfaceView -
>   com.example.x.x/com.example.x.x.ActivityHandlingFragments@5bd5b7f@0)
>   android.widget.VideoView{5bd5b7f VFE...... .F...... 0,1989-1080,2589
>   7f0a00fd app:id/videoView} D/SurfaceView: surfaceDestroyed 1 android.widget.VideoView{5bd5b7f VFE...... .F...... 0,1989-1080,2589
>   7f0a00fd app:id/videoView} V/MediaPlayer-JNI: reset V/MediaPlayerNative: reset V/MediaPlayerNative: message received
>   msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0 V/MediaPlayerNative: notify(8, 0, 0) callback on
>   disconnected mediaplayer V/MediaPlayer: resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null
>   mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false
>   mActiveDrmScheme=false
>       cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null V/MediaPlayer: resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null
>   mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
>       cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null V/MediaPlayer-JNI: release V/MediaPlayerNative: setListener
>       disconnect
>       destructor
>       disconnect D/ViewRootImpl@da487ab[ActivityHandlingFragments]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 D/SurfaceView: BG show()
>   Surface(name=Background for - SurfaceView -
>   com.example.x.x/com.example.x.x.ActivityHandlingFragments@5bd5b7f@0)
>   android.widget.VideoView{5bd5b7f VFE...... .F...... 0,1989-1080,2589
>   7f0a00fd app:id/videoView} D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x7671813a00 D/ViewRootImpl@da487ab[ActivityHandlingFragments]:
>   Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920]
>   result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
>   D/ViewRootImpl@da487ab[ActivityHandlingFragments]: Relayout returned:
>   old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1
>   surface={valid=false 0} changed=false Application terminated.

Answer (score 0):

This technique impede us from playing a video from YouTube without downloading the latter and locally storing it (as a non-temporary file). `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUA_ZvLyVFU` doesn't point to a video file, but a Web page.

To make it work I'm going to use custom video, locally stored.

In another hand, I would have been able to play this YouTube video without having to download it as non-temporary file if I used the YouTube Developer API but the app must be subscribed and I don't want that.

Comment: You can use this third party YouTube player library: https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player

The users will not need the YouTube app and you won't need to register an API key.