# Handle "Cannot play this video" in VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

Is there a way to handle the Cannot play this video in android video view programatically.

Comment: Check my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22684112/1785412

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement `MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener`
And provide it to the following `VideoView` method

```
public void setOnErrorListener (MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener l)
```

It may look like this

```
MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener onErrorListener = new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener()   
    {  
 @Override  
         public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)   
         {  
        Log.e(getPackageName(), String.format("Error(%s%s)", what, extra));
              return true;  
         }  
};
```

> **mp**    the MediaPlayer the error pertains to
>   **what**  the type of error that has occurred: MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED
>   **extra** an extra code, specific to the error. Typically implementation dependent. MEDIA_ERROR_IO MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED
>   MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT

**`MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED`** this constant represents state you are looking for.

> **Returns** True if the method handled the error, false if it didn't. Returning false, or not having an OnErrorListener at all, will cause
>   the OnCompletionListener to be called.